# UITableView with UITextField - keep the data even after user scrolls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView and it has bunch of UITableViewCells - These UITableViewCells have multiple UITextFields inside it.

Now every time I scroll up and down - and the UITableViewCells go out of the view - and comes back in whatever text I enter inside the UITextField disappears  - What is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

create an `NSMutableArray` which at each position, holds an `NSString` object which matches each cell.

when you config + show each cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, set the text of the `UITextField` to the string in the array at position `indexPath.row`.

when editing a `UITextField`, insert/update the `NSString` object at the current `indexPath.row` position in the array

Comment: Just to elaborate on this answer - for when editing the UITextField, use the UITextFieldDelegate method - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField to save the change when you edit the field, and to ensure it is saved if the cell is scrolled out of view, use the scrollview delegate method (which can be already used in a tableview controller) - (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { [self.view endEditing:TRUE];} to ensure the text field delegate method is called before the cell is scrolled out of view.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`, you need to take care of cell's state as the cell gets `dequeued` while scrolling.

You need to maintain a `Dictionary` to retain text in `UITextField` which is present in a `UITableViewCell`.

Refer my [github](https://github.com/dpakthakur/tableviewCellReuse) repo for complete solution of having UITextField / UIButton state in a uitableviewcell.

Code was created in Swift 4 with XCode 9.4