# Tableviewcell Content is moving around at scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm facing a problem and I couldn't find any solutions..

Basically I have an UITableview and the content of the cell is just an UITextField. I am adding another row to this tableview with a Button click. Here I add 1 to a counter, which displays the "numberOfRowsInSection" in my tableView. So basically the counter is at beginning 3, so there are 3 text fields at beginning. Now I can dynamically add another row by increasing the counter. After pressing the button the tableview reloads its data.

So here's a code snippet..

```
@IBAction func addPlayer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    counterPlayer += 1
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: true)
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return counterPlayer
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerTableViewCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row + 1

    cell.playerTextField.placeholder = "Spieler " + String(indexPath.row + 1)

    return cell
}
```

It works pretty well but if I write something in the first textfields, add a lot more rows and then begin to scroll, random text fields has the same content as the first textfields. Also the content of the first textfields are moving randomly to other textfields. Here is a gif, so u can better imagine.

[image]

I think the problem is the "dequeueReusableCell", so when I scroll, the first text fields will disappear, so they'll be reused and still have the content of the old ones.

Unfortunately I don't know a good way to save the old values and to display them, when I am scrolling up again...
I could solve this problem when I don't use the reusableCell and just create new unique cells, but I think that isn't a good solution..
Do u have any suggestions, how I can solve my Problem?
I think I need to cache the already filled in content somehow and then display it again, when I am scrolling up... but how?

To understand what I want to do here:
Basically the user can enter "player names" and then hit a button to perform a segue and therefor to start the game. So when he hits the button, the texts of all the tableviewcells should be passed with a segue by using an array. 
He doesn't have any player number limit.

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where does the word “test” come from?  It isn’t in the code you have shown.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mention that. I wrote test in the textfield in the running app. Then, when I scroll, it will duplicate and it moves and so on... I think its because of the dequeuereuseablecells...

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly clear the `text` property of `cell.playerTextField` in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: `UITableViews` enqueue and dequeue cells as they appear/disappear. That means the cell that just disappeared will be added as the next cell. If you want to display dynamic text based on the cell, you need to save that outside of the cell and then set it in `cellForRow` based on the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView with UITextField - keep the data even after user scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541146/uitableview-with-uitextfield-keep-the-data-even-after-user-scrolls)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by overriding `prepareForReuse` method of your `UITableViewCell` and clearing old data.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    // Clear old data to prepare the cell for being reused.
}
```

**Update:** To fix the unsaved values issue, I suggest that you create an array to hold unsaved data for each `indexPath.row`.

So, in `cellForRow` method, you'll set the current text of the text field with the data of the array in that `indexPath.row`. And when you finish editing a text field, you save the entered data in that array at the suitable `indexPath`.

Comment: First of all, thank you! But when I clear the data and scroll up again, how do I know which textfield had the content I cleared? Because it needs to be set to that data again, when I scroll up..

Comment: I'll get it, great idea! Thank you very much, I try to realize that :)